# ¿Como pasar parámetros en forma cadena en una función de Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo que pasar los parámetros de la función de mi `button` en forma de cadena.

Cuando lo hago con `PHP` me sale bien con el `json_encode` pero lo mismo quiero hacer con `Javascript`, pero no me sale.

La imagen de como debe salir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como me esta saliendo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código `JS`

```
function ActualizarEstadoAuto() {

   var urlver = $("#verAuto").attr('href');
   var urleditar = $("#editarAuto").attr('href');
    var form = $("#form-estado");
    var urld =  form.attr('action').replace('id',$("#idauto").val());


    var formdata = form.serialize();

    $("#tabla_auto").empty();

    var rows = '';

var i=1;
    $.post({
        url: urld,
        data: formdata,
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function (res) {
          $(res).each(function (key,value) {
              console.log(res);

              rows = rows + '<tr>';
              rows = rows + '<td>'+i+'</td>';
              rows = rows + '<td>'+value.modelo.nombre+'</td>';
              rows = rows + '<td>'+value.categoria.nombre+'</td>';
              rows = rows + '<td>'+value.version+'</td>';
              rows = rows + '<td>'+value.precio_soles+'</td>';
              rows = rows + '<td>'+value.precio_dolares+'</td>';
              rows = rows + '<td>'+value.estado+'</td>';
              rows = rows + '<td>';
              rows = rows + '<a  href="'+urlver+'" class="btn btn-outline btn-success"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a> ';
              rows = rows + '<a  href="'+urleditar+'" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>';
              rows = rows + '<button class="btn btn-outline btn-default" onclick="cambiarEstadoAuto('+ JSON.stringify(value.modelo.nombre)+','+JSON.stringify(value.categoria.nombre)+','+JSON.stringify(value.idAutos)+','+JSON.stringify(value.estado)+')" > <i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>';
              rows = rows + '</td>';


    rows = rows + '</tr>';

         i++;
      });

        $("tbody").html(rows);
    }

});


}
```

El problema es en el `button`.

Comment: solo cambia las comillas dobles interiores por comillas simples y el numero igual manda con comillas simples, facil y basico deberias de leer un poco mas sobre cosas como esa.

Comment: Intenta esto:`'<button class="btn btn-outline btn-default" onclick="cambiarEstadoAuto('+ "'" + JSON.stringify(value.modelo.nombre) + "'" +','+ "'" +JSON.stringify(value.categoria.nombre)+ "'" +','+ "'" +JSON.stringify(value.idAutos)+ "'" +','+ "'" +JSON.stringify(value.estado)+ "'" +')" > <i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>'` , si te funciona me avisas para ponerla como respuesta.

Comment: ya lo puse, no funciona sale mas comillas :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la hacer `JSON.stringify(valor)`, el valor generado incluye comillas dobles (`"`) y esto provoca que el `HTML` se *rompa*.

### Solución:

Una solución es, que para aquellos valores que son cadenas, agrega una comilla simple (`'`) escapada (`\`), antes y después de concatenar el valor, en lugar de usar `JSON.stringify`.

### Ejemplo:

```
rows = rows + '<button class="btn btn-outline btn-default" onclick="cambiarEstadoAuto(\''+ value.modelo.nombre+'\',\''+value.categoria.nombre+'\','+value.idAutos+','+value.estado+')" > <i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>';
```

Comment: gracias amigo esta es la respuesta !

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es que al usar `JSON.stringify` éste te genera las comillas dobles por cada parámetro que vas a enviar y esas comillas generan conflicto con las que ya tienes.

Veo una solucion y es cambiar a comillas simples el valor del atributo `onclick` para llamar la función y luego escaparlas:

```
'<button class="btn btn-outline btn-default" onclick=\'cambiarEstadoAuto('+ JSON.stringify(value.modelo.nombre)+','+JSON.stringify(value.categoria.nombre)+','+JSON.stringify(value.idAutos)+','+JSON.stringify(value.estado)+')\'> <i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>'
```

Comment: gracias camilo, pero necesito pasar como cadena , al hacer lo que me mandaste no me reconoce como cadena necesito que quede asi  "..", si lo mando asi me sale error por que tiene un espacio las oraciones

Comment: @ingswsm ah entiendo, y aplicando el escape al momento de llamar la función tampoco te funciona?

Comment: gracias camilo por tomarte el tiempo camilo ya puse la respuesta correcta

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline btn-default" onclick="cambiarEstadoAuto('Buster boyle','Automoviles','1,0')"> contenido de botón </button>
```

**En el Javascript:**

```
rows = rows + '<button class="btn btn-outline btn-default" onclick="cambiarEstadoAuto(\''+ JSON.stringify(value.modelo.nombre)+'\',\''+JSON.stringify(value.categoria.nombre)+'\',\''+JSON.stringify(value.idAutos)+'\',\''+JSON.stringify(value.estado)+'\')" > <i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>'
```

Comment: pero los datos que estan dentro de la funcion estan como variables <button class="btn btn-outline btn-default" onclick="cambiarEstadoAuto('+ JSON.stringify(value.modelo.nombre)+','+JSON.stringify(value.categoria.nombre)+','+JSON.stringify(value.idAutos)+','+JSON.stringify(value.estado)+')" > <i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>';

Comment: nada amigo , tu codigo me da mas comillas gracias

Comment: gracias shassain

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a usar comillas dobles, dentro de esas comillas dobles deben tener comillas simples, sino, el navegador lo interpretará como variables o como sus semejantes, sean funciones nativas o no nativas de javascript. Lo mismo pasa si usas comillas simples, dentro de una función deben ir comillas dobles, excepto si vas a usar variables.
Intenta esto:
`rows +='<button class="btn btn-outline btn-default" onclick="cambiarEstadoAuto(\"'+ value.modelo.nombre+'\",\"'+value.categoria.nombre+'\",\"'+value.idAutos+'\",\"'+value.estado+'\")" > <i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>';`

PD: a tu variable rows, en vez de usar rows = rows +'...HTML...' podrías usar rows+='...HTML...', es lo mismo pero mucho mas simple, quita menos trabajo.

Comment: gracias, pero mee sale con mas comillas

Comment: Si, perdon, se me habia olvidado el JSON.Stringify, quitaselo!

Comment: gracias angel por el tiempo ya puse la respuesta correct